# Is the extension of the antiderivative differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $F$ be its antiderivative. Suppose there exists a finite limit $\lim_{x\to 0} F(x)$. We can extend $F$ to a continuous function by defining $F(0):=\lim_{x\to 0} F(x)$. The question is: Is $F$ differentiable at $0$?

When $f$ has a limit $\alpha=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ by l'Hospital' rule we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}F'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\alpha$$

which means $F$ is differentiable when this limit is finite.

The problem is when $f$ does not have a limit as $x$ tends to $0$. In this case there are examples of functions when $F$ is differentiable (take $F$ which is differentiable but the derivative is not continuous at $0$), but I haven't found an example when it is not differentiable. That's why I'm looking for a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: $F(x) = \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: I'm looking for a counterexample when the limit of $f$ doesn't exist (neither finite nor infinite). I know that when it is infinite the antiderivative is not differentiable.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x}$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. The antiderivative is clearly differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Take $f(x)= (-\frac{\cos(1/x)}{x})+\sin(1/x).$ Its antiderivative is $x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$, which can be continuously extended to $0$, but is not differentiable there.